# Change the id of the body tag from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm curious:
Is it possible to change the the id of the body tag from code-behind (in ASP.Net Webforms)?

I want to change

```
<body id="test">
```

to

```
<body id="foo">
```

without having to use a second MasterPage. (Our designer provided two different html/css files where the id of the body tag is different. Except for that small difference, I could use the same MasterPage)

Do I really need to create another MasterPage, just for the different body tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `bodyId` variable in the MasterPage:

```
<body id='<%= bodyId %>'>
```

And then you can set the variable from the content page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on client side too.

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/fTvpQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

ID of page elements is same as name of variables, can you change them? if yes you can do this also, if no, it's possible!